# How to run protractor tests with ng-idle module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, ng-idle

I have installed `ng-idle` module to my **AngularJS** application.

I set up this module next way:

```
.config(['IdleProvider', IdleProvider => {
  // Timer before logout (seconds)
  IdleProvider.timeout(60);
  IdleProvider.keepalive(false);
}])

.run(['Idle' 'user', (Idle, user) => {
  // user is a service
  if (user.loggedIn)
    Idle.watch();
}]);
```

Everything works perfectly. But now I am trying to run protractor tests, and they are failing with the next error:

> **Failed:** Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular

Without this module, every test passed.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ensured that it is not an issue of missing file / ngAnnotate?

Comment: @felixmosh yes, I ensured. The problem is with timeout inside this module.

Comment: @felixmosh it works perfectly. But when I run tests, it broke them.

Comment: Checkout that thread https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4584#issuecomment-373182891

Comment: And that ... https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169

Comment: From the post above protractor should not wait on @interval, I've checked the source code of ng-idle and it uses $interval, do u use old angularJS version?

Comment: @felixmosh no, I am using angular 1.6.9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168283/discussion-between-vadim-shashkov-and-felixmosh).

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: @LuninRoman we decided to avoid this module because it doesn't work correctly in Safari and IE.

Comment: Oh, indeed? I will revise my own code then, thanks for the quick response!